# POST with angular $http and Chrome's REST client gives 400 Bad request error

Tags: spring, rest, post, get

I am trying to make a REST call to my spring controller on jboss

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
String myMethod(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
    String json = null;
    String METHOD_NAME = "getAuditForRecordId";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {
        json = gson.toJson("success");
    }

    return json;
}
```

My angular post call

```
$http.post(<URL to myMethod>, postData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(function () {
                d.resolve(response);
            }).error(function () {
                d.reject();
            }
        );
```

is failing with a 400 Bad request error. I have a CORSFilter for my jboss app

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) resp;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type");

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

GET methods inside the same controller are working fine. But this above POST fails.

**My POST JSON object has nested objects.**

I also tried the same POST call from Chrome's REST client but still get the same error. Can someone point to the obvious mistake I am making here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's in the data I am passing with my post request. I had one extra property in my passed-in nested Object. When I changed the data model on my server side to include that extra property my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the url on the post is allocated in other domain, not in the same domain that are your project running, you dont call url form other domain.

This is my example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listAll.json", params = {"page","pageSize","order","filter"},  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"})
@ResponseBody
public String listAll(@RequestParam("pageSize") int pageSize, @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("order") String order, @RequestParam("filter") String filters){ 
    return this.pilmotiformService.listAllIntermediario(pageSize, page, order, filters);        
}

@RequestMapping(value = "updateRecord.json", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"})
@ResponseBody
public String UpdateRecord(@RequestParam("cons") Long cons) throws Throwable{}
```

From Angular:

```
myApp.service('myService', function($http, $rootScope, $routeParams) {          

this.oneFunction = function() {                     
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: WEB_SERVER+'/oneMethod.json',
        params: {modulo: 'FMT_FORMREGI,FMT_AUDITORIA,FMT_ESTADO,FMT_ADJUNTO,PIL_USUA,PIL_MOTIVO,PIL_MOTIFORM' }
     });
 } 

this.otherFunction = function(one, two, three) {        

    data = {one : one, two : two, three : three};

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: WEB_SERVER+'/otherMethod.json',
        data: data
     });
 }
```

});

Comment: GETs in the same controller are working fine. Only POST fails. I believe there's something to do with the data I am posting. Do you think so?

Comment: In your controller mvc of spring you put  produces={"application/json"} ? see my example complete, that works for me, i used every day, maybe you dont include jackson mappin. are you?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson mapper is the component that convert or serialize the data to entitys.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i think what you are missing here is the that json is in this format

```
{"key" : "value"}
```

and you are trying to do `"success"` so may be this is what you are missing.

I may be wrong as i have not working on gson or json a lot